# ¿Dónde se guardan las variables de este código en C?

Tags: c, linux

Con el siguiente código:

```
int *p;
int A[256];
int main(int argc, char *agrv[]) {
    int *q;
    int j;
    int num[123];
}
```

Según entiendo el puntero *p al ser una variable global se debe guardar en la zona .data (del espacio de memoria de este proceso) pero su contenido se guarda en el heap.

A[256] al estar inicializado y ser global se almacenará en la zona .data

El puntero *q al ser local del main se almacenará en el .stack pero su contenido se guardará en el heap

La variable j al ser local del main se almacenerá en el .stack.

Y el array num[123] al estar inicializado en el local del main se almacenará en el .stack

No sé si es así o el tema de los punteros y arrays funciona diferente.

Comment: aun no entiendo porque quieres saber donde se guarda cada variable?

Comment: mira si tu objetivo es saber los punteros apuntan a la memoria por lo que puedes apuntar con este a el principio de un array de esta manera p = num; que apunta a la primera ubicacion de memoria de este. todo cambio que hagas en p se refleja en num puesto que apuntan al mismo espacio en la memoria

Comment: si no es eso lo que querias saber se mas explicito

Comment: @AlexRivas sí eso lo sé, quería saberlo por temas de un examen que tendré. No sé si es la manera correcta como lo puse arriba. Pero el punto es saber dónde se guardan todas estas variables:)

Comment: creo que tu respuesta puede ser esta [ve aqui](https://elrincondelc.com/foros/viewtopic.php?t=13934)

Comment: dime si te sirvio de ayuda

Comment: @AlexRivas No tel todo, pero he encontrado esto que da la base teórica de lo que preguntaba: [enlace]https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/  aunque sigo sin saber el contenido de un puntero global si guarda su informacion en el heap o en el data segment.

Comment: como que se inicializa un array? creo que el puntero va donde mismo el array pues este es un puntero al primer espacio de memoria donde estan sus datos. Eso creo es bastante logico pensarlo

Comment: ¿No vale hacer `gcc -S -masm=intel test.c`?